# how to dynamically route requests

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, squid

I have this network,

red - 3 computers with internet connection - every computer has its own different connection to internet (over VPN)

blue - proxy server, squid

green - computers in my local network)

[image]

Anytime are always 2 of 3 red pcs on and blue pc knows, which 2 blue pcs are currently online. Now, what I need to do is, how should I set blue computer to randomly send communication from green computers over random 2 red computers (which are online of course - for example this hour is online first and third red pc, in the next hour will be online first and second red pc).

Any idea how to do it?
I prefer solution (as I said to randomly route requests through random 2 reds).

I thought I can reconfig blue squid each time and reload configuration. But this has bottleneck, when there are many requests from green computers, they could lost connection.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really need is a router with multiwan features.  Something like pfsense can handle having 2 or 3 internet providers and load balancing betweeb whichever ones are available at the moment.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that these 3 connections are VPN (edited in my question). So there is no need to have 3 lines in one router, I just want to make it with software "routing" (not changing hardware)

Comment: @peter what is the purpose of these separate vpn connections?  Typical setups would only have one vpn connection, or would require certain connections to go through a particular vpn, not routed randomly.

Comment: these more VPNs are for backup purposes (and for now for testing purposes as well)

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like dynamic loadbalancing
when using squid you may use time based ACLs to handle this

> acl aclname time [day-abbrevs] [h1:m1-h2:m2]

http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/

Answer (score 0):

If this is a VPN, then you could use some sort of dynamic routing, like OSPF or iBGP with [Equal Cost Multipath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-cost_multi-path_routing) routing support, announcing default gateway from the remote end.